# Xamarin.Forms: List gets longer than there are items inside listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

This is my grid inside a scrollview:

```
            <ScrollView>
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <Button  Text="asd1" x:Name="row1" Grid.Row="0"/>

                    <Grid  x:Name="row2" 
                           Grid.Row="1"  
                           IsVisible="false"                           
                           Margin="30,0,0,0" 
                           BackgroundColor="Yellow">


                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ListView x:Name="list_cat1"
                                  Grid.Row="0">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding subCatName}" >
                                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GetClick"/>
                                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Label>
                                        </Grid>
                                        
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                                
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>

                    <Button Text="asd3"  x:Name="row3"  Grid.Row="2"/>
                </Grid>


            </ScrollView>
```

But this is me feeding it data_

```
    private void SetCategories()
    {
        List<CategoryType> allCatsInsideSubs = FilteringSingleton.Instance.GetCategories();

        List<SubCategoryType> sub1 = new List<SubCategoryType>();

        for(int i = 0; i < allCatsInsideSubs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (allCatsInsideSubs[i].categoryOrder == (int)CategoryOdersEnum.Deko)
            {
                SubCategoryType x = new SubCategoryType();
                x.subCatName = allCatsInsideSubs[i].subCategory;
                x.subCatID = allCatsInsideSubs[i].subCategoryOrder;
                sub1.Add(x);
            }

        }

        list_cat1.ItemsSource = sub1;


    }
```

But the result is this:

[image]

As you can see, the list is way longer than there are items in it. You can actually scroll down a little while more until the yellow stops and the next button becomes visible. Every row is set to auto. Where is this extra space coming from?

I did also notice that when I put more data into the listview, it is no longer too long

Comment: a ListView will fill its parent container.  It does not automatically size itself based on its contents

Comment: Oh ok, how can I bypass this?

Comment: calculate a height and assign it to your ListView

Comment: yeah, i pretty much did that now. not happy with it but ok :) thanks

Comment: @inno Hi, have you solved it?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT hey there, yea i did by simply giving it a fixed size. looks quite alright.

Comment: @inno Great! If so, remember to update the solution in answer, and mark it when you can. It will be helpful for others who have the same problem.